# Getting all the rows of a List which with distinct on one column

Tags: c#, list

I have a C# list in which there are several columns and rows of data and I am trying to retrieve few of the rows by applying distinct on one  column of the list.

For example I have the following data in a `C# list AxiomSubSet` of type `AxiomDS`

```
Month   Strk    Strg    Price   Amount
15-May  3.80    Put     0.0410  200
15-Apr  3.80    Put     0.0410  200
15-Mar  3.80    Put     0.0410  200
15-May  4.20    Put     0.0380  100
15-Apr  4.20    Put     0.0380  100
15-Mar  4.20    Put     0.0380  100
15-May  4.25    Call    0.0620  60
15-Apr  4.25    Call    0.0620  60
15-Mar  4.25    Call    0.0620  60
```

When I apply a method to above `list` it should the first row for each distinct `Strk` like

```
Month   Strk    Strg    Price   Amount
15-May  3.80    Put     0.0410  200
15-May  4.20    Put     0.0380  100
15-May  4.25    Call    0.0620  60
```

and store the above data in a temporary list of same type

I tried something like

```
List<AxiomDS> listTempStrikes = new List<AxiomDS>();
listTempStrikes = AxiomSubSet.Select(x => x.strike).Distinct().ToList());
```

but not working for obvious reasons. May I know a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `GroupBy`

```
listTempStrikes = AxiomSubSet.GroupBy(x => x.Strk).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

You can also use the `DistinctBy` method from the [`MoreLINQ`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library

```
listTempStrikes = AxiomSubSet.DistinctBy(x => x.Strk).ToList();
```